Wide input range Dual Edge Trigger Input (P-Channel N-Channel Linked Pair)
i'm working on a design where I would like to tolerate both source and sink currents as valid inputs, along a wide input voltage range.
Specifically, I would like to have an output logic high for both scenarios of a single pin having current sourced or sunk, with an input range of 0V-20V. I would like the threshold for the high side input to be ~+4V, but tolerant to inputs near +20V. Simultaneously, I would like the same pin to be sensitive to current being sunk above a certain threshold (lets say 50mA).
I want both of these options to trigger a logic level high on the output, which is normally pulled low.
My initial thought was to use a P-Channel and N-Channel MOSFET in parallel, one triggering off of the high side and one off of the low. My initial design is shown in the screenshot below and linked:
Design Link

Input sweeps from 3-15V, output goes high from 5V-15V, low elsewhere. Output is high if GND switch is on, assuming top switch is off. Application wouldn't ever have both switches on.
Is there a better way to do this? Current requirements are very low, the output of this is a digital input on a microcontroller. I'm not sure if this is a normal thing that I do not know the name of. Biggest issue I see with this is that it requires tuning of gate threshold voltages to some extent.
I have looked at Schmitt trigger chips, however they would require significantly more components total by my initial checks, and don't quite accomplish what I want.

Are you familiar with a window comparator arrangement?

@TimWilliams I was not, however I am not sure that they would work properly, as most ICs require that the supply voltage be near or greater than the expected maximum input voltage. I suppose that I could either clip the incoming signal with zeners, or clip the output and choose a higher supply voltage, however I would prefer to stay away from Zener clipping where possible.
